# VBA - sort the data from excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an case what i don't know how to deal with that, can someone suggest or give me some idea to solve it ?

**Summary**: I have an Excel file with 3 columns (Name, user , password), this is an example. As you can see in column A , there are 2 cell with name jack , 1 is  his user ID (row 2) , and the other is his password. I wish they can stored in the same row , sth like that cell A2 is jack , cell B2 is his user name (jck), and C2 is his pwd (123).
my code as below

```
Sub test()
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set sh2 = wb.Sheets(2)
    Dim rng As Range
    last_row = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    last_row2 = sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox last_row
    For i = 2 To last_row - 1
        For j = i + 1 To last_row
            If sh.Range("A" & i).Value = sh.Range("A" & j).Value Then
                    If IsEmpty(Range("B" & i)) Then
                        sh2.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Value = sh.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Value
                        sh2.Range("B" & i).Value = sh.Range("B" & j).Value
                    End If
                    If IsEmpty(Range("C" & i)) Then
                        sh2.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Value = sh.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Value
                        sh2.Range("C" & i).Value = sh.Range("C" & j).Value
                    End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Could you please help look ? Any assist will be appreciated.

Comment: `but it doesn't accurately arrange` - What is accurate in your definition?  And excel already has a sort function, have you tried that? We don't write code for you so please make an attempt and re-post/edit your question with the code and show an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that you use the same row counter for Sheet2 as you do for Sheet1.  Since you will end up with half the number of rows with data in Sheet2, that will result in gaps in Sheet2.  You will need a seperate row counter for Sheet2

Another issue is you have several unqualified Range references, so whether this works or not will depend on which sheet is active.

A third issue is you haven't declared all your variables.

You code, refactored

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim last_row2 As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rw2 As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set sh2 = wb.Sheets(2)
    last_row = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    last_row2 = sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox last_row
    rw2 = 1
    For i = 2 To last_row - 1
        For j = i + 1 To last_row
            If sh.Range("A" & i).Value = sh.Range("A" & j).Value Then
                If IsEmpty(sh.Range("B" & i)) Or IsEmpty(sh.Range("C" & i)) Then
                    rw2 = rw2 + 1
                    sh2.Range("A" & rw2 & ":C" & rw2).Value = sh.Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Value
                    If IsEmpty(sh.Range("B" & i)) Then
                        sh2.Range("B" & rw2).Value = sh.Range("B" & j).Value
                    ElseIf IsEmpty(sh.Range("C" & i)) Then
                        sh2.Range("C" & rw2).Value = sh.Range("C" & j).Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```